# If I put a 64 bit distro (OS System) in my 32 bit computer and it runs is that okay? Is it safe?

Tags: hardware

I found I can put a 64 bit software (OS system) into a a 32 bit computer. I did it by installing the 64 bit software (OS system) into a 64 bit computer first without adding any updates. Then I removed the hard drive and put it into a 32 bit computer and it works. Then I updated it as well. I just hope it does not cause any unknown problems.
Please let me know is this safe?

Comment: What do you mean by "a 32 bit computer"? If your CPU is 32-bit only, a 64-bit system won't boot.

Comment: Well I did it on a couple of old laptops already with linux mint and MX lunux. I installed it on a 64 bit laptop first with 64 bit software, then I took the SD drives out and put it in my 32 bit laptops and it works. – Tony D Alessandro 3 mins ago

Comment: Probably they were  not "32 bit laptops" but laptops with a 32-bit OS installed. see the difference?

Comment: Those could also be pentium 5 with PAE @pilot6 :) Technically 32 bit systems

Comment: PAE can't run 64-bit code. They can address memory in a way 64-bit CPU would, so the RAM limit is not an issue.

Comment: Please add information about what you are calling "a 32-bit laptop". Otherwise it makes no sense.

Comment: In the second comment above I saw reference to Mint and MX Linux, but not of Ubuntu or any of it's official flavors. I am cutting to close this question as this is not about Ubuntu.

Comment: The 32-bit computers that have 64-bit software right now is the hp compaq 6910p and the hp elite 8440p. I used a 64-bit computer (hp compaq 8510p) to install the 64-bit software then I removed the hard drive and put it into the 32-bit computers named above. Normally the 32-bit laptops named above will not install and run 64-bit software. My question really is ... is it safe to run a computer this way is there a security problem?

Comment: You can install 32-bit software to literaly any computer. It doesn't tell anything about the hardware. The laptop models don't tell anything. There are no "security problems", but as many people told you before, you can't run 64-bit code on a 32-bit CPU. Are you trolling?

Comment: HP Compaq 6910p specs:  CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo T7300 2.00GHz. Your Core 2 Duo is a 64 bit based BIOS system. My old laptop from 2006 is core2 and is now running 64 bit 20.04 Kubuntu. Is a bit slow but I am now used to new fast desktops with SSD drives.

Comment: Hello Pilot6 you mentioned "you can't run 64-bit code on a 32-bit CPU." This is exactly what I did. I am running a  64-bit code on 32-bit CPU. If you do not believe me that's okay.

Comment: So what is the CPU? How do you know it's 32-bit? Core2Duo is a 64-bit CPU.

Comment: @TonyDAlessandro please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `sudo lshw -C cpu` and `uname -a`

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02030599 shows CPU as early I-series CPU. It is 64 bit and may be UEFI. But probably works better with BIOS unless HP has much newer UEFI as an update.

Answer (score 1):

32-bit computers cannot run 64-bit code, so the installer would not get very far. If you would like to give a 32-bit computer a new OS, you'll need to find one of the few distros out there that still offer 32-bit support.

Comment: Well I did it on a couple of old laptops already with linux mint. I installed it on a 64 bit laptop with 64 bit software, then I took the SD drive out and put it in my 32 bit laptop and it works.

Comment: 64-bit laptops can run 32-bit systems, but reverse isn't true.

Comment: Well I got a couple of laptops doing the reverse. The trick is to install it the 64-bit software on the 64-bit laptop first. Then remove the hard drive from the 64-bit laptop and put it into the 32-bit laptop. It works pretty well. The real question is, Is there a security problem running my laptop this way?

Comment: @TonyDAlessandro it's because those aren't actually 32-bit computers. Almost all x86 CPUs since Pentium 4 Prescott released in 2000 are 64-bit CPUs. You can hardly find any 32-bit x86 CPUs for the last 15 years except a few early Atom CPUs

Comment: PAE can be 32 bit that can run 64 bit .

Comment: If this is true it is it impossible to add a 64-bit software into a 32-bit computer directly the way we normally do. I found by using the aid of a 64-bit computer to install it first and taking the hard drive out and putting it into the 32-bit hard drive computer it works.

Comment: If it is a real 32-bit computer, you can't do it either way.

Comment: I checked the CPU on the Elitebook 8440p it says 64 type, but it will not accept any 64-bit OS. It will only accept when I install it on my 64 bit computer and move the hard drive to the Elitebook 8440p. I found this in all my old laptops. However if its a 64 bit computer then it should be safe. I have a much older computer which I am going to try to see what happens.

Comment: `it will not accept any 64-bit OS` then you've installed it incorrectly. For example you created a UEFI installation disk and use it to boot a BIOS machine